# How to populate datagridview with a database which has a relationship?

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

Is there any way that I can populate the `Datagridview` with the records in the database which has a relationship? I want to show all records in one `Datagridview`. I searched the `Google` but I can't find any solution or sample code. Here's my code:

```
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM employee"

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)

    Dim dt As New DataTable("employee")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    ' Assigns our DataSource on the DataGridView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    '
    Dim sql1 As String
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM employee"
    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, con1)
    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(sql1, con1)

    con1.Open()
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    myreader.Read()
    con1.Close()
```

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT * FROM employee` do an sql join on the 2 tables you're after. Then display that data set.

Comment: I'm using access as database. I've read that there is an `INNER JOIN` statement which I have to use the `INNER JOIN` keywords in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT`statement. Please correct me if I've read the wrong article to use in my code....

Comment: You're probably on the right track. This will display all records that appear in both tables. If your parent table contains some records which do not have child records then these wont display. If you need this then an `outer join` is what you're after.

Comment: I have five tables. `EmployID` is my `primary key` in my main table and a `foreign key` in the other four. Should I use the `inner join`?

Comment: Try it and find out. It'll display all details for all employees provided that the employee has a record in every table. If some of these tables don't have data for that employee then no row will appear for that employee.

Comment: Sure. I'll try it out :) Thank you, sir :)